# Product page (Related.php) error in Magento 2.1.16

Tags: magento2, overrides, related-products

I override the page Related.php and add my extra custom function in this class it works perfectly on 2.2.X but in 2.1.16 it shows me this error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home2/hide/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Related.php on line 129

now I don't why is it giving this error n how can I solve this error on 2.1.16 on 2.2.X its works perfectly.

Comment: could you share code of `Related.php` ?